# Class's superclass and String's superclass

Tags: ruby, superclass

`Class` has its superclass `Module`, but any class, like `String`, has the superclass `Object`. Why is it?

Comment: That is not true. `Integer` has the superclass `Numeric`.

Comment: `Module` is an `Object` making `Class` also an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

To get it clear, you need to check out [*Object model*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Class.html) of Ruby :

*Classes*, *modules*, and *objects* are interrelated. In the diagram that follows, the vertical arrows represent inheritance, and the parentheses meta-classes. All metaclasses are instances of the class `Class`.

```
                         +---------+             +-...
                         |         |             |
         BasicObject-----|-->(BasicObject)-------|-...
             ^           |         ^             |
             |           |         |             |
          Object---------|----->(Object)---------|-...
             ^           |         ^             |
             |           |         |             |
             +-------+   |         +--------+    |
             |       |   |         |        |    |
             |    Module-|---------|--->(Module)-|-...
             |       ^   |         |        ^    |
             |       |   |         |        |    |
             |     Class-|---------|---->(Class)-|-...
             |       ^   |         |        ^    |
             |       +---+         |        +----+
             |                     |
obj--->OtherClass---------->(OtherClass)-----------...
```

All your questions can be answered by looking at the diagram above.

> but any class, like "String", you get the superclass "Object". Why is it?

Look the `OtherClass` in the diagram. `Hash`, `String`, `Array` etc all are `OtherClass`.

> in Ruby, the "Class" itself has the superclass "Module"

That's how it is designed, again can be answered from the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, everything is object including class while classes themselves are also objects. 
`String` object has its own class called `Class`.
`String` by itself is a class as well and String's superclass is 'Object'.

Meanwhile, `Class` itself is an object too, however the superclass is `Module` which is by design of Ruby language.

Comment: Could you please wrap language concepts / keywords with ` characters? This will give a nice formatting for this words like `this`.